# How to rate-limit a pipe under linux?

Tags: linux, pipe

Is there a filter which I could use to rate-limit a pipe on linux? If this exists, let call it rate-limit, I want to be able to type in a terminal something like

```
cat /dev/urandom | rate-limit 3 -k | foo
```

in order to send a a stream of random bytes to foo's standard input at a rate (lower than) 3 kbytes/s.

Comment: I asked here because I want to use it in a programme, not for troubleshooting. But it's my very first question here so I apologize if I made an error.

Comment: BTW, the above is an unnecessary use of cat, you could do `rate-limit 3k < /dev/urandom | foo`.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) has this feature.

```
cat /dev/urandom | pv -L 3k | foo
```

From [the `pv` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv):

> **-L RATE, --rate-limit RATE**
>
> Limit the transfer to a maximum of **RATE** bytes per second. A suffix of "k", "m", "g", or "t" can be added to denote kilobytes (*1024), megabytes, and so on.

Comment: Also handy to use while watching output of a job, with `-q`... e.g: `command 2>&1 | pv -q -L 3k`

Answer (score 17):

I'd say that [Juliano has got the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464476/how-to-rate-limit-a-pipe-under-linux/2464503#2464503) if you have that tool, but I'd also suggest that this is a neat little K&R style exercise: just write a specialized version of cat that reads one character at a time from `stdin`, outputs each to `stdout` and then `usleep`s before moving on. Be sure [to unbuffer the standard output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/1004590#1004590), or this will run rather jerkily.

I called this `slowcat.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){
  int c;
  useconds_t stime=10000; // defaults to 100 Hz

  if (argc>1) { // Argument is interperted as Hz
    stime=1000000/atoi(argv[1]);
  }

  setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);

  while ((c=fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){
    fputc(c,stdout);
    usleep(stime);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile it and try with

```
$ ./slowcat 10 < slowcat.c
```

Comment: Now I'm feeling the horrible temptation to add a "clack" noise to each character an set the default speed to 40 CPS, with an extra delay for newlines.

Comment: I'd use that with one of those retro terminal screensavers for a giggle if I had speakers attached to my linux boxes.

Comment: You do not need to unbuffer the output if you just use the `write` syscall directly.

Answer (score 7):

[throttle](https://linux.die.net/man/1/throttle) seems designed *specifically* for this. e.g.

```
cat /dev/urandom | throttle -k 3 | foo
```

Comment: I would agree with this, but there doesn't seem to be a standard package for Ubuntu. I also am not seeing the source code for it either. Anyone know where you can get this utility?

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber It looks like the [website that normally hosts the code](http://klicman.org/throttle/) is offline, but freebsd has the source for 1.2 available on their [ftp server](ftp://ftp.fi.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/throttle-1.2.tar.gz). You would have to download it there & `./configure && make`.

Comment: I added the source to [github](https://github.com/mrjimenez/throttle) in case someone want to change stuff to make it compile on newer machines.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an all-shell solution that won't lose input (cf. the head -1 idea from Mike S):

```
hexdump -c /dev/urandom | (lines=0; while read line; do echo $line; if [ $((++lines % 10)) -eq 0 ]; then sleep 1; fi; done) | cat -n
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty, all shell all the time (I have CentOS and pv doesn't come with it by default):

```
hexdump -c /dev/urandom | while true; do head -1; sleep 1; done | \
your_program_that_reads_stdin  -your_argument_list
```

...dirty because although it's rate limited, it's bursty at a rate that I can't tell you :-) . But it's handy when you just need to send data from one place to the other (I was doing some socat tests) and you don't want to swamp your screen with garbage.