# shell pipe back pressure similar to "pv"

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I have shell file like this:

```
grep 'INSERT INTO container' $file | mysql database -f
```

Problem I have is MySQL gets too many inserts and it slow down a lot (database is mostly read-only and this is only insert).

I want to have something that can slow down the speed / control pipe "bandwidth", similar to this one:

```
grep 'INSERT INTO container' $file | gzip -9 | gunzip | mysql database -f
```

Here `gzip -9 | gunzip` will slow down the process and pressure to MySQL will be low.

`pv` command happen to have abilities like this, but it is interactive command. I am looking for something non-interactive.

Comment: maybe this http://www.itsprite.com/linux-does-tee-slow-down-pipelines/ or this one http://superuser.com/questions/239893/how-to-rate-limit-a-pipe-under-linux, but maybe you don't want to compile and want to use some standard tool

Comment: Surely using `sleep` is better than `gzip -9 | gunzip`?

Comment: cat I pipe sleep? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

You should use pv with the option `-q` which from the manual :

```
-q, --quiet
    No output.  Useful if the -L option is being used on its own to just limit the transfer rate of a pipe.
```

So using the command `grep 'INSERT INTO container' $file | pv -L 100 -q | mysql database -f` should do what you want.
Maybe 100 is too slow, but you can put like 5k or more if you want.

Comment: Is it doing what you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use insert-delayed (deprecated in latest version)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html

Comment: this is the other thing we are checking in parallel